# dependency between engine and 3d model software. Resolution - what is it really

Tags: unity, unreal-4

I have a few questions about gamedev as a beginner.

1) Why someone tells that Unreal Engine has better graphic then for example Unity? I can create any quality model in 3ds max, for example, and import to Engine. Will this model look different in UE4 Editor and Unity Editor ?

And pls tell me do I understand it correct - each graphical engine (UE4, Unity and 3ds max) has own algorithm for drawing. And some one can render 10k poly for 1 second and another for 5 sec and that's why people say that one engine looks better then another, just because the same object render faster without lags. Is it true?

2) About game resolution - as I understand, model doesn't have resolution. Raster graphics has resolution, texture has resolution, but not model.

Again pls tell me, am I right or not - when I'm selecting in game resolution, I'm changing texture\material resolution ? If it's true, so how can we say that this game has Full HD or 4k resolution when each model can have many different textures with different resolution? For example, Call of Duty had good characters resolution, very clear, but at the same moment, walls or boxes looked worse then Minecraft. So resolution option just something virtual, because each object has own resolution?

Comment: why my question get downvote ? Is my question stupid and google search result first 10 post will answer me? Why some people here so angry and why admins don't controll it ?

Comment: First, nobody has control over (or visibility into) downvotes. That's just how StackExchange works. Second, it also works in a fashion that we generally prefer you to ask a single question per post, rather than two fundamentally different questions as you have here. Normally I'd edit one of them out, but since you've already gotten an answer that would invalidate that answer, so instead I've closed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1** - It will look different depending on a number of factors, such as:

- Lighting (A horrifically underrated aspect of game development)
- Shaders

**2** - Correct, models don't have a resolution. The level of model detail is measured in vertices, polygons and edges. Whilst raster graphics and textures do, models are very different. The way that a game is *4K* or *HD* is because of the display size it supports. It has nothing to do with models or textures, only window/screen size.

If this answer was no help, please tell me!

(btw good question)

Comment: thank you, but have a few questions - if texture doesn't change, so if you want to say that your game support 4K, you should add as default texture with high resolution? because you can try to open first Doom in Full HD, but it will look not better then 800x600. Is this because game has low resolution texture ?

Comment: And how does it works, that some games give you more visible places. For example battlefield gives you more sidelong visibility, but Dota - not. What different between this 2 game resolution rendering. Just in few words, not need full explanation

Comment: Models have resolution in the sense of triangle density, or number of vertices/faces per unit area. This can be changed through GPU tesselation but it's still worth paying attention to the base density of a mesh as a parameter in asset creation.

Comment: @FoxNet if you want to ask another question, make a new question post. Comments are not for extended discussion.